# Is any way able to pass a column list into values constructor in merge statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl

I tried to find a way to pass a column list into values constructor in merge statement. Any idea?
The reason is we have a lot of source tables and want to update target table for each of source tables by using merge. If merge statement find not matched, inserting to target should be choose. However, in this insert statement, it ask for a column list of source. That means I have to list each of column of source table. It is so tedious for each table that I am wondering if any way to pass it as a parameter. Appreciate for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly (?), I'd create a proc that dynamically builds the merge SQL statement.  Create a cursor on the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns sorted by table_name, loop though it to build a dynamic string, run sp_executesql for each table_name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [approach](http://sql-ex.ru/help/select20.php) based on INFORMATION_SCHEMA and FOR XML PATH.